# d3 Bubble Chart mixing v3 and v5 on scale

Tags: d3.js

I am struggling with a mix of d3 v3 and v5 versions when trying to render a bubble map.  Can someone assist this struggling D3.JS newbie with this relatively simple code on codepen?  There is no error messages in teh console area so I am stuck...

```
enter code here
```

https://codepen.io/tbellmer/pen/NWPExJV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In d3 [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale) you can find that `.domain` and `.range` methods take array as argument. So, change

```
var countScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(1, 13)
  .range(3,15);
```

to

```
var countScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([1, 13])
  .range([3,15]);
```